# Convert derived class to generic class type with the same public functions, while still being able to call the function of the derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting

In the program hereafter, I have a class animal, that has derived classes cat and dog with the same public functions but different private functions. I would like to let the user decide during runtime which animal is being created. I have made a simple example that shows what I approximately want, but which obviously doesn't work. I don't know how to solve this and would like to have your help.

```
#include <cstdio>

class canimal
{
  public:
    int sound()
    {
      std::printf("...\n");
      return 0;
    }
};

class cdog : public canimal
{
  public:
    int sound()
    {
      std::printf("Woof!\n");
      return 0;
    }
};

class ccat : public canimal
{
  public:
    int sound()
    {
      std::printf("Mieau!\n");
      return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
  canimal *animal;
  cdog    *dog;

  // I would like to let the user decide here which animal will be made
  // In this case, I would like the function to say "Woof!", but of course it doesn't...
  animal = new cdog;
  animal->sound();

  // Here it works, but I would like the pointer to be of the generic class
  // such that the type of animal can be chosen at runtime
  dog    = new cdog;
  dog->sound();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As the below answers already discussing that you should make `sound()` as `virtual`. Also note that since you are doing dynamic allocation using `new`, you must have a `virtual ~canimal()` destructor as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the `sound()` method `virtual`:

```
class canimal
{
  public:
    virtual int sound()
    ^^^^^^^
```

This will make it behave exactly as you need.

For further discussion, see [Why do we need Virtual Functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/can-someone-explain-c-virtual-methods)

In C++ 11 there is a new `override` keyword that, when used appropriately, makes certain types of errors less likely. See [Safely override C++ virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497630/safely-override-c-virtual-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to make sound() virtual. Read up on polymorphism in C++.

```
class canimal
{
  public:
    virtual int sound()
    {
      std::printf("...\n");
      return 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `virtual`

i.e.

```
class canimal
{
  public:
    virtual int sound()
    {
      std::printf("...\n");
      return 0;
    }
};

class cdog : public canimal
{
  public:
    virtual int sound()
    {
      std::printf("Woof!\n");
      return 0;
    }
};

class ccat : public canimal
{
  public:
    virtual int sound()
    {
      std::printf("Mieau!\n");
      return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess if I don't want to introduce another level of inheritance, I do not need to make the derived functions virtual?

Comment: You could also make `canimal` a pure virtual function so that only derived objects can be created. This is done by `virtual in sound() = 0;`