# Polymorphism is not working with function return values of same data type (Base and Inherited class)

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

As far as I know to override virtual function in the inherited class the function should have the same data type of the return value as the base class function.

But the compiler will accept changing the return value if you return a pointer or value which belong to a class inherited from the class of the return value of the original function as following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
virtual  Base * clone() {
    std::cout << "Base::clone()\n" ;
    Base * bp = new Base ;
    return bp ;
}
  std::string ID() {return "Base class";}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  //Derived* and Base* are same data type (acceptable):
  Derived * clone() {
    std::cout << "Derived::clone()\n" ;
    Derived * dp = new Derived ;
    return dp ;
}
  std::string ID() {return "Derived class";}
};


int main() {

  Base * bp = new Derived;

  std::cout << bp->clone()->ID() <<"\n";

  std::cout << dynamic_cast <Derived*>(bp->clone())->ID() <<"\n";
  /*
  next code give error: cannot convert Base* to Derived*: 

  Derived * dp2 = bp->clone();
  std::cout << dp2->ID() << "\n";
  */
}
```

the output by g++ is:

```
Derived::clone()
Base class
Derived::clone()
Derived class
```

Overriden `clone()` function in `Derived` class returned a pointer to a copy of the same object on heap.  As seen from output the right version of `clone()` is called every time but not `ID()`. To solve this problem I had to downcast the return value to get the desired effect by `dynamic_cast` or to make `virtual ID()` in base class.

My Question: why polymorphism didn't work in the first case

```
  std::cout << bp->clone()->ID() <<"\n";
```

as `clone()` should return  a pointer to an Object from `Derived` class and consequently the `ID()` function of `Derived` class not `Base` class, but in this case I have `ID()` function of the `Base` class ?

Comment: did you forget `virtual` in front of Base::ID? Currently it is not a polymorphic function.

Comment: No , I already test this option as I said in my question. actually I intended not to use virtual keyword to test the output of ID().

Comment: But your question is why polymorphism didn't work *without* the downcast. The reason is the ID function is not virtual.

Comment: How compiler should know if `bp` is `Derived` if you said it's type is `Base`? Apparently, everything is clear because you call `clone` as if it was method of base class.

Comment: my Question is clone() will return Derived* pointer,  So when I call clone()->ID  why the return value is treated as Base* pointer . So I why virtual should be used?

Comment: Because you are calling `ID()` through a `Base*`

Comment: @Galik why is it a `Base*`? The covariant `virtual Derived* Derived::clone()` should return a `Derived*` though...

Comment: You can call a Derived object through either a `Base*` or a `Derived*`. To get the correct `ID()` the function needs to be virtual or you need to call through the `Derived*`.

Comment: @Galik , Ok, but the clone() virsion belong to Derived and return Derived* pointer not Base* pointer

Comment: It is not the return type that determins the call but the pointer type that the returned type is bound to. In this case that's a `Base*`.

Comment: `Base* bp` will *always* be a `Base*` even if you bind a `Derived*` value to it.

Answer (score 2):

The polymorphism is working properly in that case. The reason the code is printing `Base class` when you expect `Derived class` is because the `ID()` method is not `virtual`.

In order to understand what happens, you have to look at the code as if you were the compiler. In your example, `bp` is a pointer to a `Derived` instance but it has been typed as `Base *` in the code so the compiler sees a `Base *`. When the compiler later in code sees `bp->clone()` it knows that the `clone()` method of the `Base` class returns a `Base *`. Finally when the compiler reaches the `->ID()` method call, it looks at the `Base` class definition and sees a *non-virtual* method so it ensures that at runtime, the `Base::ID()` method is called at that location.

If you want to have polymorphic behaviour, add `virtual` keyword for both ID() methods. You could also add [`override`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609941/197371) keyword on `Derived::ID()` if you use a C++2011 compliant compiler.

Comment: What's not clear for me is the following: `bp->clone()` performs a virtual dispatch, so it invokes the `Derived::clone()` via a `Base*` pointer, nothing fancy here. However, the latter returns a `Derived*`, so, the return type of `bp->clone()` should be `Derived*`. It actually isn't, it is `Base*`, why is this?

Comment: The compiler can not know at compile time that the `clone()` call will return a `Derived*` so it goes by what the variable `bp` is defined as.

Comment: @vsoftco  Exactly,  this is what I mean from my question

Comment: @vsoftco The virtual dispatch means the compiler has no idea at compile time what type will be returned by `clone()` function, only that it will be a derivative of `Base*`. The only way the compiler can track the correct type returned by `clone()` is by virtual dispatch and that can only happen if `ID()` is also declared virtual.

Comment: @Galik, it makes sense, but then what's the whole reason of introducing this funky covariant return type? I mean, what's the advantage vs simply writing `Base* Derived::clone() override` ?

Comment: @vsoftco I suppose the covariant return type allows you to bind the `Derived*` to a `Derived*` variable when `clone()` is called through a `Derived*` rather than a `Base*`.

Comment: @Galik good point! Gotta figure out exactly how this whole business works, I could have bet that the type of the returned pointer is `Derived*` even if called via a `Base*`...

Comment: @Galik , it makes sense

Comment: @user3270926 I posted a very similar question to yours, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29179208/3093378 The idea is (I think) that the compiler must know the type at compile time (not at run time), so the type deduction is statically bound. That is, the type of `bp->clone()` is the type of the invoking pointer, in this case `Base*`, and not what `bp->clone()` returns via the virtual dispatching.