# Covariant clone function misunderstanding

Tags: c++, c++11

This question is related to a very recent one 
[Polymorphism is not working with function return values of same data type (Base and Inherited class)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29179035/3093378)

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual  Base * clone()
    {
        Base * bp = new Base ;
        return bp ;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived * clone() override
    {
        Derived * dp = new Derived ;
        return dp ;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Base * bp = new Derived;
    auto funky = bp->clone();
    std::cout << typeid(funky).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `P4Base` (i.e. pointer-to-Base). Why is this? `bp->clone()` should invoke the covariant `virtual Derived* Derived::clone` via a `Base*` pointer, so the type of `bp->clone()` should be `Derived*`, not `Base*`.

Comment: You're checking the type of the pointer, you're not checking the type of the pointed to object. Btw. better declare the `clone` functions as `const`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf and why is the type of the pointer `Base*` since the overridden function declares its return type as `Derived*`? If it still returns a `Base*`, what's the whole reason behind the covariant type return?

Comment: The covariant return is only of benefit to code that knows a more specific type than the topmost base class. Anyway, declaration types are compile time. Object types can be more dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
auto funky = bp->clone();
```

is equivalent to

```
Base* funky = bp->clone();
```

since `Base::clone` returns a `Base*`.

Checking the type of that pointer then yields `Base*`.

Checking the type of the pointee is a different matter, when the `Base` type is polymorphic. And in the presented code `Base` is polymorphic because `clone` is virtual. To understand more of this functionality, check the type of the pointee instead of just the type of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks! So the type deduction is statically bind, right? I think that's what I was missing, I thought `bp->clone()` calls `Derived::clone`, which returns a `Derived*`. But now I see that it is impossible for the compiler to use run-time type deduction, as the type deduction is made at compiler time...

Comment: `bp->clone()` does call `Derived::clone` in this case, but you still have to save the result in a `Base*` variable if `bp` is also of type `Base*` to keep type safety, because the compiler can't know that `bp` is a pointer to `Derived` when it's of the type `Base*`.