# Covariant return type invalid conversion error

Tags: c++

I am trying out the covariant return type and have the following code

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        cout << "this is from Base " << endl;
        return new Base(*this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Derived* clone() const
    {
        cout << "this is from Derived " << endl;
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* d = new Derived;
    Derived* d2 = d->clone(); // invalid conversion from ‘Base*’ to   ‘Derived*’
    return 0;
}
```

Why the line `Derived* d2 = d->clone();` gives an invalid conversion error, since it is the type `Derived *` that `clone` is returning in the `Derived` class? If I change it to `Base* d2 = d->clone();` it runs, but it also prints
"this is from Derived" indicating it's the `clone` in the `Derived` called.

Comment: `.clone()`: insert java into c++... error: invalid argument... error: insert c++ into java ... error: invalid argument...

Comment: repeated question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/29179035/3270926

Comment: @Youssef: Not really, no.

Comment: @Youssef this question is more about the type mismatch rather than polymorphic behaviour. The marked dupe matches perfectly though.

Comment: @lightnessRacesinOrbit and vsoftco :    Ok, I understand your points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Derived* d2 = d->clone();
```

The compiler checks the types at compile type, and `d` has type `Base*` (even if at runtime the virtual dispatch kicks in and indeed a `Derived*` object is returned from `d->clone()`). In your case it is OK to use a `static_cast` (no need for `dynamic_cast` really), like

```
Derived* d2 = static_cast<Derived*>(d)->clone();
```

I think all of us got confused by this issue at least once. Related: [Covariant clone function misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179208/covariant-clone-function-misunderstanding).