# How does an inheritant class work in this situation ???

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class A {
public:
    A() { foo(); }
    ~A() { foo(); }
    void foo() { cout << 3; }
    void bar() { foo(); }
};
class B : public A {
    void foo() { cout << 2; }
};
int main() {
    B b;
    b.bar();
    return 0 ;
}
```

I compiled and ran it . The result is  333 
... but I thought: when I call b.bar() . It would be directly to bar() and then call foo() function which is in class B because foo() in class A is overridden in class B . The result I thought is 323 . But I was wrong. Have I missed something ? Please help me to explain how it atually works @

Comment: I think you wanted a `virtual foo()`

Comment: My two cents here: 1) even if you implement foo() as a virtual function, once called in "A" constructor it will run A::foo() instead of B::foo() because there is no "B" created yet; 2) you MUST NOT call any virtual function in destructors because "B" can be destroyed already and dereferencing B::foo() pointer can crash the app, or deal with the already-overwritten memory, or something else. And here we don't talk about virtual inheritance yet, it would make the things way more tricky.

Answer (score 3):

THe problem is that you have a non virtual `foo()` so that `A::bar()` will call the only `foo()` it knows, being `A::foo()`,  even if it's B that invokes it.

Try:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { foo(); }
    virtual ~A() { foo(); }             // <<---------- recommendation
    virtual void foo() { cout << 3; }   // <<<--------- solves it
    void bar() { foo(); }
};
class B : public A {
    void foo() override { cout << 2; }  // <<---------- recommendation
};
```

**Additional infos:**

Making `foo()` [virtual](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/) in the base class allows each class to override this function, and be sure that the `foo()` that is invoked is will be the `foo()` corresponding to the object's real class.

It's a [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497630/3723423) then to use the keyword `override` in the derived classes: it's not mandatory, but in case you make a typo in the functions signature, you'll immediately notice with a compile-time error message.

Another good practice is to make your base class destructor virtual if you have at least one virtual function in the class.

A final remark:  in B, `foo()`'s private.  This is legal, but it's weird because the inheritance says that B is a kind of A, but you can't use B objects exactly as an A object.

Answer (score 0):

Member `A::foo` is non-virtual and will therefore be statically bound wherever used. So when compiling `A::bar`, the call to `foo()` will be (statically) bound to the implementation `A::foo()`. This statical binding in `A::foo` will not be changed  by the fact that you create an instance of derived class `B` later on. 
If you call `b.foo()` in you main, however, `B::foo` will be bound.

In order to have `B::foo` to be called through `A::bar`, you'll have to declare `A::foo` as `virtual:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { foo(); }
    virtual ~A() { foo(); }
    virtual void foo() { cout << 3; }
    void bar() { foo(); }
};
```

Note that you'd also declare the destructor as virtual; non-virtual destructors do very rarely make sense.

Answer (score -1):

You must include virtual in order to override the functionality stored in A.

Add to A

```
virtual void foo() { cout << 3; }
```

and to B

```
void foo() override { cout << 2; }
```

Should do the trick. Virtual functions are member functions whose behavior can be overridden in derived classes. As opposed to non-virtual functions, the overridden behavior is preserved even if there is no compile-time information about the actual type of the class. If a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class, a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior defined in the derived class.